# How do I do random access reads from (large) files using node.js?

Tags: node.js, seek, random-access

Am I missing something or does node.js's standard file I/O module lack analogs of the usual file random access methods?

- `seek()` / `fseek()`
- `tell()` / `ftell()`

How does one read random fixed-size records from large files in node without these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tell` is not, but it is pretty rare to not already know the position you are at in a file, or to not have a way to keep track yourself.

`seek` is exposed indirectly via the `position` argument of `fs.read` and `fs.write`. When given, the argument will seek to that location before performing its operation, and if `null`, it will use whatever previous position it had.

Comment: The times I use `tell` are mostly when I'm reading text in platform-agnostic code line-by-line which could have lines ending in either `\n`, `\r` (no longer common), or `\r\n`. It's certainly still possible to track position without `tell` though.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else who might read this thread, I missed the `position` parameter because in my reading of the docs I managed to conflate it with the `offset` parameter, which is the offset from the start of the buffer you want to read data into.

Comment: This works great for reading records from binary files, but I also need to read lines of text from passed file offsets. It turns out to be very difficult to read a single line of text using `fs.read` due to the nature of `Buffer` and the need to convert such to encoded text such as UTF-8. The obvious ways result in broken characters since UTF-8 includes multibytes characters. `ReadableStream` handles multibyte characters, but does not allow one to seek freely. I'm not sure there's any library which lets you combine random access and line reading.

Comment: @hippietrail The two are kind of at odds with each other unfortunately. This isn't really a common issue. That said, please create a new question if you want answers to this. Reading lines from random positions is independent of your original question here.

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth I will ask a specific question. I just wanted to get my thoughts linked in here too before my internet credit last night ran out. Though my use case (indexing offsets into very large text files - Wikipedia XML dumps) is not "common" I have implemented it before in C, Perl, and even JavaScript in a FireFox plugin so I was surprised it was so tricky in node considering how much better node is that those environments in various ways.

Answer (score 2):

node doesn't have these built in, the closest you can get is to use `fs.createReadStream` with a `start` parameter to start reading from an offset, (pass in an existing `fd` to avoid re-opening the file).

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: Unless this turns out to be slow it seems like a perfect solution. It could depend on the cost of creating a ReadStream from an fd.

Comment: Do I also need to pass in the same path parameter each time I call `createReadStream()` again? The `path` is mandatory while the `fd` is just optional and the docs are not clear.

Comment: hm... have you tried passing in `null` for path, even though it says it's required? otherwise i'd just pass in the same path.

Comment: Yes I've since tried it and the "required" `path` is ignorned no matter what it is if you also supply the optional `fd`. This doesn't seem to be guaranteed explicitly in the documentation or stated so in the source. Also I can find nothing authoritative by searching the forums. I am loathe to rely on a behaviour that's not documented even if backed up by common sense. I might find a way to ask officially. Thank you yiding.

Comment: I ran into problems when trying to use this multiple times for each time I want to read from some position in the same file: [createReadStream multiple times on the same fd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015757)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that createReadStream creates new file descriptor over and over. I prefer sync version:

```
function FileBuffer(path) {
const fd = fs.openSync(path, 'r');

function slice(start, end) {
    const chunkSize = end - start;
    const buffer = new Buffer(chunkSize);

    fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, chunkSize, start);

    return buffer;
}

function close() {
    fs.close(fd);
}

return {
    slice,
    close
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
fs.open(path, flags[, mode], callback)
```

Then this:

```
fs.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)
```

Read this for details:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback