# Random access in node.js

Tags: node.js, random-access

Does node.js support writing random access?

I see [this package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/random-access-file), but it doesn't work (if I write two or more parts, the file is corrupt)

Comment: You mean like accessing data in a file after particular offset location ?

Comment: @user568109: Yes, I have, for example. file it size is 1024 KB, and I get it in chunks of 256KB. So I want to write the first chunk in 0 offset. the second in offset 256, and so on.

Comment: sounds like streams would fit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do random access reads from (large) files using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932967/how-do-i-do-random-access-reads-from-large-files-using-node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[fs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) core library should suffice for that. Here is the list of functions to use:

1. [fs.open(path, flags, [mode], callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback)
2. [fs.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)
3. [fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, offset, length, position)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position)
4. [fs.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)
5. [fs.readSync(fd, buffer, offset, length, position)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position)

They are analogous to how you would do it in C.

Comment: @OrSmith Can you add the code to the question and tell what you are trying to do. I cannot understand the above code.

Comment: No, it doesn't. when I upload 2 parts or more, I see that my file contains some source code of the middleware package. I use `app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});`. It can be related?

Comment: @OrSmith bodyParser has been deprecated. If you use older version, I suggest you use a recent version. Otherwise the problem could be difficult to find/solve.

Comment: Thanks, but I use the latest version: `4.4.3`