# Changing portion of file without rewriting the entire file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, read-write

Right now I use readStream, and then do some modifications and then write the processed line into a .tmp file. After writing is done it is renamed to the original file name. The drawback it has to write even the unchanged lines which just makes it really slow

Is it possible to edit a file with the cursor position like (x, y) just those bytes  without rewriting the entire file in NodeJS?

Comment: hi Keerthi Vasan, Welcome to SO. Please Read [How to ask a good question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random access in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230135/random-access-in-node-js)

Comment: No actually it doesn't, I want a package to write let's say 5th line and replace the 5th line alone instead of rewriting the whole file or maybe it's not possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The functions [fs.write](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/fs.html#filehandlewritebuffer-options), [fs.writev](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/fs.html#filehandlewritevbuffers-position), [fs.createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatewritestreamoptions) all accept an option called 'position' (or 'start' in fs.createWriteStream) to set the editing byte cursor position. You can use these functions to edit a specific part of the file without overwriting the entire page.

However, this requires you to have a clear clue about the relation between line position and its corresponding byte position.

For example,

```js
const nameByteCount = 20;

const add = (name) => {
    const fd = fs.openSync('file', 'a');
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(nameByteCount);
    buffer.write(name); 
    fs.write(fd, buffer, (err, bytesWritten, buffers)=>{
        console.log('-error', err)
    });
}

const update = (nameIndex, name) => {
    const fd = fs.openSync('file', 'a+');
    const buffer = Buffer.from(name);
    fs.write(fd, buffer, { position: nameIndex*nameByteCount }, (err, bytesWritten, buffers)=>{
        console.log('-error', err)
    });
}

add('Tom');
add('Jerry');
update(1, 'Jerry2'); // will only update jerry to jerry2
```